# merging rows to a single row in pandas based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like

```
Time       C1    C2
08:00:20   5     nan
08:00:40   nan   6
08:05:12   10    nan
08:05:32   nan   14
```

I want to merge rows closely related in time to a single row and remove nulls from my dataframe, some thing like this

```
Time    C1    C2
08:00   5     6
08:05   10    14
```

Can someone help me with how to merge rows to get such outputs

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

If `Time` is string use indexing by first 5 values and pass to [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.pop('Time').str[:5]).first().reset_index()
print (df1)
    Time    C1    C2
0  08:00   5.0   6.0
1  08:05  10.0  14.0
```

If `datetime` in column use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df1 = df.groupby(df.pop('Time').dt.strftime('%H:%M')).first().reset_index()
print (df1)
    Time    C1    C2
0  08:00   5.0   6.0
1  08:05  10.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bfill`  and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df[['C1', 'C2']] = df.groupby('Time').bfill()
df.drop_duplicates('Time')

    Time    C1    C2
0  08:00   5.0   6.0
2  08:05  10.0  14.0
```